# Can't click to next page with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

So i've been using selenium to try to automate the signup for swimming spots from my local ymca. I have this page, and i'm trying to click all the lap checkboxes then click to the next page.

[Lap Signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCltD.png)

That page has this html code:

```
> <main class="scheduleVisitOnline container" role="main">    <!-- See
> app.jsx for React component -->    <div
> id="schedule-visit-wizard-app">
>     <div class="chooseMembersStep">
>      <h1 class="page-title">
>       Schedule a Visit
>      </h1>
>      <p>
>       <strong>
>        Ann Arbor YMCA
>       </strong>
>       <br/>
>       <a href="#">
>        Change Branch
>       </a>
>      </p>
>      <div class="chooseMembersStep__members">
>       <label class="control-label">
>        Select visiting members and any reservation-only areas you intend to utilize
>       </label>
>       <table class="chooseMembersStep__members-table">
>        <tbody>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member">
>          <td>
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input checked="" id="member_3572218" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td colspan="2">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__member-name" for="member_3572218">
>            Patrick McKeever
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_39b9bf20-6493-4bd8-b2c4-6f6a4ab5a69d" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_39b9bf20-6493-4bd8-b2c4-6f6a4ab5a69d">
>            Hoops M-F / 7-8a /- 2 Half Courts (1 reservation per member family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_9a486991-672e-4a87-9130-05f379344968" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_9a486991-672e-4a87-9130-05f379344968">
>            Hoops M-S / 8a-8p /- 4 Half Courts (1 reservation per member family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_23d2d590-475d-44cd-84fd-c071bf299f89" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_23d2d590-475d-44cd-84fd-c071bf299f89">
>            Indoor Wellness Center
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_b6470dcf-ab5d-44e5-85e2-4a50a1f7ffc7" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_b6470dcf-ab5d-44e5-85e2-4a50a1f7ffc7">
>            Lap Pool - Lane 1 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_34b69cbf-c890-4090-912e-1a2e32c805a9" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_34b69cbf-c890-4090-912e-1a2e32c805a9">
>            Lap Pool - Lane 2 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_7f453950-a5ba-424a-ac1e-a8c968519ab7" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_7f453950-a5ba-424a-ac1e-a8c968519ab7">
>            Lap Pool - Lane 3 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_28fed658-ad4e-4721-8b90-d6c943f0fac9" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_28fed658-ad4e-4721-8b90-d6c943f0fac9">
>            Lap Pool - Lane 4 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_c22ab33c-7850-4a52-a6e9-8737647ea54f" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_c22ab33c-7850-4a52-a6e9-8737647ea54f">
>            Lap Pool - Lane 5 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_24177575-8769-405b-af6a-5e5afdb10c56" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_24177575-8769-405b-af6a-5e5afdb10c56">
>            Lap Pool - Lane 6 (1 reservation allows 4 members from same family account)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_0ee4cec1-2149-4af5-9c76-22abc6574d64" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_0ee4cec1-2149-4af5-9c76-22abc6574d64">
>            Showers (Reservation only necessary if you don't have a reservation in another area of the building)
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-area">
>          <td>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-checkbox-col">
>           <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve">
>            <input id="3572218_084dfd23-3ab5-4624-bcc8-bb7f8a25d30d" type="checkbox"/>
>            <div class="state p-success">
>             <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewbox="0 0 20 20">
>              <path d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
> style="stroke: white; fill: white;">
>              </path>
>             </svg>
>             <label>
>             </label>
>            </div>
>           </div>
>          </td>
>          <td class="chooseMembersStep__member-area-name-col">
>           <label class="chooseMembersStep__area-name" for="3572218_084dfd23-3ab5-4624-bcc8-bb7f8a25d30d">
>            Track
>           </label>
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="chooseMembersStep__member-spacer">
>          <td colspan="3">
>          </td>
>         </tr>
>        </tbody>
>       </table>
>      </div>
>      <div class="ctas">
>       <button class="btn" type="button">
>        Back
>       </button>
>       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
>        Next
>       </button>
>      </div>
>     </div>    </div>    <div style="clear: both;">    </div>   </main>
```

and i've been using this python code to click the 6 elements and click the next button:

```
wd.maximize_window()

actions = ActionChains(wd)

for chk in wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[.//label[contains(.,'Lap Pool - Lane')]]")[:4]:
  actions.move_to_element(chk).click(chk).perform()

wd.fullscreen_window()

wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="schedule-visit-wizard-app"]/div/div[2]/button[2]').click()
```

I just got help on clicking the six swimming boxes, but it still doesn't seem to be going to the next page. Idk if that's because the swimming boxes aren't actually selected, or it doesn't click next, but the html code after I run that html code is the same.

Indicating the page hasn't changed. Any ideas?

Also if anyone knows how to render the current state of the webdriver/webpage so i can see what's happening that would be great for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for button to be clickable.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use either `xpath` or `css selector`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn.btn-primary"))).click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and contains(.,'Next')]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```